# Reason to start download in same tab vs new tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, web

I would like to know why and what is the difference between starting a download in the same tab / a new tab. Clicking the link will eventually start downloading, despite it's a new tab or same tab.

So can anyone explain me, what is the significance of doing this? Any help is appreciated :)

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/g5Gn5/30/)

```
<a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.zip" >Current Tab Download</a><br>

<a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.zip" target='_blank'>New Tab Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual behaviour is just a matter of settings the right `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type`.
Starting in a new tab is usually just a work around for when the right HTTP headers are not set server-side.

Only exception I could think of would be for PDF files, if you want the user to be able to see the document right in the browser (through a PDF viewer) without navigating out of you website/app then yes, opening a new tab/popup could actually make some sense.

Answer (score 0):

New tab is generally preffered when you want to preserve the content of the current tab and you want it to be their in the browser hoping user would want to come back to it. Because our site should never be left behind.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I got you but my scenario is when user clicked the download link, the browser opens a new tab -> start download -> close the tab automatically. Hence the user would be in same page only. so it doesn't make sense to open a new tab.

Comment: But i guess if you will do it on the current tab then it will get closed, Which probably you would not want.

Comment: Its just Branding, Branding and Branding. Coz anyway user can press "Back Button" or Can "Undo Close Tab" but as i said our site should never be left behind.

Comment: If you are starting download in the same tab, then why would you close the tab. The scenario for current tab download is,  When the link is clicked, the download will start automatically and the user would be in same page. I have a feeling that developers are doing this for some reason.

Comment: But say you have `pdf` or a `song` and the user has a plugin installed on his/her browser to show/play the file instead of downloading it (which is a highly probable case). Now if user will click on your link and the link opens up in the same tab then user will loose your page(which you probably dont want).

Comment: I think it would be clear if I present you code and explain, just check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/g5Gn5/30/

Comment: from the above fiddle, can u tell me what is the significance of doing this. In which cases we should follow the above 2

Comment: In case of `.zip` i dont this their is much difference, but considering the file to be a `pdf` or a `song` it would be a different case.